# Singeleton - error: [CFString isNSString__] message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton

I have an NSMutableArray in a singleton, which I want to access in two classes. I've done this in another project exactly like this (that one had ARC, this one doesn't) and it worked there.

**Project doesn't have ARC on.**

I'm getting the error:

```
*** -[CFString isNSString__]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xb3d1db0
```

StoreVars.h

```
@interface StoreVars : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *sharedArrayOfVideo;
+ (StoreVars *)sharedInstance;
@end
```

StoreVars.m

```
@implementation StoreVars
@synthesize sharedArrayOfVideo;
+ (StoreVars *) sharedInstance {
    static StoreVars *myInstance = nil;
    if (myInstance == nil) {
        myInstance = [[[[self class] alloc] init] retain];
        myInstance.sharedArrayOfVideo = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return myInstance;
}
@end
```

Populating the array asynchronously:

```
NSDictionary *tempDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                      ID,@"id",
                                      title,@"title", nil];
[[StoreVars sharedInstance].sharedArrayOfVideo addObject:tempDict];
```

This is where crash happens:

```
 NSLog(@"%i",[[StoreVars sharedInstance].sharedArrayOfVideo count]);
 NSLog(@"%@",[StoreVars sharedInstance]);
 if ([[StoreVars sharedInstance] respondsToSelector:@selector(sharedArrayOfVideo)]) {
        **NSLog(@"%@",[StoreVars sharedInstance].sharedArrayOfVideo);**
       //NSLog(@"%@",[[StoreVars sharedInstance].sharedArrayOfVideo objectAtIndex:8]);
}
```

Output:

```
10
<StoreVars: 0xb381b00>
*** -[CFString isNSString__]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xb3d1db0
```

Comment: is your program getting crash on  NSLog(@"%i",[[StoreVars sharedInstance].sharedArrayOfVideo count]); or some other line?

Comment: It's crashing after the if statement (when trying to access an element of the array), count shows 10.

Comment: The Zombies instrument can tell you the retain/release history of the deallocated object. Use that to look for the missing retain or (as you found) extra release or autorelease.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem, when creating the dictionary, I did:

```
NSString *ID = [[[arrayOfEntry objectAtIndex:index] objectForKey:@"id"]; autorelease]

NSString *title = [[[arrayOfEntry objectAtIndex:index] objectForKey:@"title"] autorelease];
```

Instead of:

```
 NSString *ID = [[arrayOfEntry objectAtIndex:index] objectForKey:@"id"];

 NSString *title = [[arrayOfEntry objectAtIndex:index] objectForKey:@"title"];


 NSDictionary *tempDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:ID,@"id",title,@"title", nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a question with regards to the line below in your code:

```
if ([[StoreVars sharedInstance] respondsToSelector:@selector(sharedArrayOfVideo)])
```

Q. Why have you tried to check the  mutableArray as method via selector ?

If you want to iterate through the added dictionaries do the following

```
StoreVars *storeVars = [StoreVars sharedInstance];
if(storeVars.sharedArrayOfVideo.count>0)
{
   for(int i=0; i<storeVars.sharedArrayOfVideo.count; i++)
   {
      NSDictionary *dictionary = [storeVars.sharedArrayOfVideo objectAtIndex:i];

      // do stuff with the grabbed dictionary.
   }
}
else { NSLog(@"sharedArrayOfVideo is empty"); }
```

Further in your singleton creation code perform the following edit:

Instead of following:

```
if (myInstance == nil) {
        myInstance = [[[[self class] alloc] init] retain];
```

Use the following:

```
if (myInstance == nil) {
        myInstance = [[StoreVars alloc] init]; 
        // you already own the above object via alloc/init, so no extra retains.
```

Comment: And how exactly would I do that? (PS: That line of code was inserted by a colleague of mine who's trying to fix the bug).

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. You can use the "add comment" link below the question to ask the author for clarification.

Comment: Yes, Martin R this is not an answer. but I wrote it because of the code portion. Adding codes in comment is very cumbersome. And once I was clear on my query, I'll do an edit on this answer itself to make it a complete answer. Which I will do now.

Comment: @Lord : Assuming that you need to access dictionaries from your array. Check my edit.

Comment: Did the edit, added NSLog(@"%@",dictionary); under the //do stuff, and getting the same error: *** -[CFString isNSString__]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xc8a33c0. And that retain was just a simple punch in the dark, maybe that makes it work.

Comment: Check my edit again for changing the creation of Singleton. Further, you need to write dictionary.description to print the dictionary. Example : NSLog(@"%@",dictionary.description);

Comment: NSLog(@"%@",dictionary.description); => *** -[CFString isNSString__]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xb65da50

Comment: This is odd. Try initialising the arrayOfVideo inside the init method of StoreVars. Also, let me know, in object of which other class are you trying to access this dictionaries ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to create singleton with gcd like this:

```
static ASBTLEManager *sharedInstance = nil;

+ (ASBTLEManager *)sharedManager
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[ASBTLEManager alloc] initInstance];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way to create singleton instance, this is more accurate than what you are trying

```
+(StoreVars *) sharedInstance
    {
        static StoreVars * myInstance = nil;
        static dispatch_once_t oneTimePredicate;

        //get calls only once.
        dispatch_once(&oneTimePredicate, ^{
            myInstance = [[self alloc] init];
            myInstance.sharedArrayOfVideo = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        });
        return myInstance;
    }
```

Comment: Same crash happens: *** -[CFString isNSString__]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xb3bb810